# How can i display icon and hide it with condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I display the `visibilty icon` only if  `item.Sampling_Instructions` > 0 ?

else do not display the `visibilty icon`.

```
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from 'native-base';


const dataArray = [
      { title: 'Modeling method', content: item.Sampling_Method_Code },
      {
        title: 'Detail of containers',
        content: customTableContent,
      },
      {
        title: 'Additional guidelines',
        content: [
          [`frequency: ${item.Sampling_Frequency_Name}\n`],
          [`Laboratory: ${item.Lab_Site_Name}\n`],
          [`time: ${item.Extraction_Time}\n`],
          [`device: ${name}\n`],
          [`Instructions: ${item.Sampling_Instructions}\n`],
        ],
        icon: 'visibilty',
      },
    ];
```

Comment: You have already asked similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
{item.Sampling_Instructions > 0 ? <yourVisibilityIcon> : null}
```

This is conditional rendering and you have to call it where your Icon would be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
icon: {item.Sampling_Instructions > 0 ? 'visibilty' : ''}
```